# how to collapse navbar in twitter bootstrap after click on link if it woud be collapsed because of css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the navbar from this example twitter bootstrap page.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Because of responsive design the navbar content will be replaced by a symbol = (consisting of three lines)

User Scenario:
on navbar i click on the symbol =
then i see the menu
then i click on a link
then i want the menu to be collapsed again with the = symbol IF css has collapsed it with current screen size

Javascript code that remembers the state before and replaces the state again is not acceptable in my solution, because this is too ugly. I want to do it without repeating conditions of the twitter bootstrap css.

BUT i want that the css will be evaluated again on the navbar.

After the link is clicked, i want to restore the navbar to the state before i clicked the = symbol. The navbar should be evaluated with the css again, and if the css makes the navbar to a = symbol is should be, if it displays the navbar, then it should. But i want it be handled by the css itself. Is this possible, to reevaluate it?

Comment: If you've made an attempt to do this, you should show what you've tried and explain how it fails to accomplish what you want. If you have not made an attempt yet, you should do so now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove "in" class when click on link in the collapsed navbar using jQuery.
Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
        $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass('in');
    })
});
```